# TERADATA: how to create a SQL statement with an autoincrement number?

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm just in front of a difficult task. I should select the amount of transactions from a Teradata database done per hour.

A possible output could be:

```
2014-08-04 01:00 500
2014-08-04 02:00 650
2014-08-04 03:00 720
...
```

The count itself contains the amount of transactions done i.e. between 0:00 and 01:00, second line from 01:00-02:00, and so on.

I'm not bad in normal SQL statements, however, this exceeds my knowledge, unfortunately. Anyone having a good idea on how to solve this? Many thanks in advance.

Regards, Thomas

Comment: Are you asking how to group by hour?

Comment: As Andrew already asked: Dou you want to know how to group by hour or how to create a result row if there's no data for this specific hour, or both?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table TDATA with columns TDATE and assuming TDATE is text in the format '2014-08-04 13:52:17.5632' then this would work.

```
select
  mid(tdate,1,13) + ":00" as ActivityHour,
  count(*) as Transactions
from
  tdata
group by
  mid(tdate,1,13) + ":00"
```

Depending on the dialect you might be able to use left(field,13)

If your date is in a different format you can convert it first.